# Animation plays in 3fps even in low poly proxys

Tags: animation, linked-data

Animation plays really slow when animating. we are looking for the reason in the original library of assets and in the animation project. Do someone know a possible reason for this behavior?

Tanks!

Comment: How complex is your scene?

Comment: we have 3 characters rigged  wirh drivers to off the modifiers and subdivisions. The characters, scenary are in 1 linked file. And a 2nd file with the lightset. The most of the objects are turned off because we are animatig gesture and lipsync.

Comment: i'm not sure what is up, but it could be how fast the computers you are using are.  One thing I can suggest is using openGL playblasts, (if your not sure how to do those, I can show you.)

Comment: eird thing is the procy was doing well but it start to fail specially when animating a particular character. we are trying to figure out whats with this character... I other files it works good.

Comment: well, I hope you can figure it out, What is different about this character from the others?